# Laravel change job connection to a different database

Tags: laravel

How can I dispatch my jobs to SQLite and not my MySQL connection? My main connection is MySQL and I need to specify the connection because my SQLite has the correct tables. I do not want to change my DB_Connection in my env file because I need both connections.

I tried `FilterBroadcastMessage::dispatch()->onConnection('sqlite');` but this
`"connection"` is referring to the `"connection"` in my `config/queue.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem.

Added the `config/database.php` `connection` to my `config/queue.php` `database` connection.
And changed `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `database` in `.env` file.

```
'database' =>[
              'connection' => 'sqlite',
              'driver' => 'database',
              'table' => 'jobs',
              'queue' => 'default',
              'retry_after' => 90,
             ],
```

Comment: Thanks @Neavehni you have saved my day!

Comment: Why this is not working for me? In my case worker still tries to fetch jobs from default database connection